# Installing virtualbox inside VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vagrant

I have got citrix desktop VM as my main machine to work in my office.
I want to develop on linux rather than on windows. So i am trying to install virtualbox.

I installed virtual box and vagrant.

Now when i try to start the `ubuntu/trusty32` vagrant box. Then

1. First i got VT-x disabled error

Then i disabled PAE mode in processors but after that i get error that Guest is trying to turn on PAE mode which is disbaled.

Is there any way to fix that issue or its not possible at all

Comment: The virtualization software must support VT-X, VirtualBox has problems with doing this, VMWare does not.

Comment: You can probably get virtualbox running with hardware virtualization disabled: http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/virtualization/6274d1337874487t-vm-machine-trouble-virtualbox-system-settings-acceleration.png ; it would be pretty slow though

Answer (score 3):

Point is that virtualization within virtualization must be supported by both your physical CPU and your "outer" virtualization software. Often, that feature is even disabled in virtualizers (because you seldomly nest VMs).

Also, my experience is that virtualbox isn't really the system of choice for remote machines; if you want to, uninstall it (the vbox kernel modules conflict with other virtualizers' kernel modules) and try KVM.

Generally, I'd not recommend putting VMs inside VMs, unless you have a damn good reason. A Linux dev environment easily fits on a <20€ USB3 stick and can be carried around. More importantly in a corporate environment, your IT department should just give a developer a functioning VM to install Linux in if the dev needs that. Everything else would be like a company that hesitates to give out pencils for their employees.

Comment: We are only given Virtual machines via wyse terminal , USBs are also not allowed

Comment: In a restrictive environment like that, you clearly should get your own Linux VM.

Comment: And containers are often a better approach to segregation within a vm.